# Mapping serialized webservice response using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am having a little issue trying to map the response of a WS into an autocomplete input.

The response i get looks like this

```
    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"AirportList":[],"CityList":[{"ExtensionData":{},"Code":"ZRH","Country":{"ExtensionData":{},"CallingCode":"41","Code":"CH","CurrencyCode":"CHF","Name":"Suiza"},"CountryCode":"","Latitude":"4736902","Longitude":"853803","Name":"Zurich"}],"CountryList":[],"RegionList":null,"ExtensionData":{},"Messages":null,"SessionKey":"","Success":true}
     </string>
```

That response has 3 segments but im interested only in *CallingCode* and *CountryCode*.

Here's the method im using to get the info out of it,

```
callAjax('POST', 'ListCitiesByNameFilter', { filter: req.term }, false, function(data) {
                                    res($.map(data, function(item) {
                                     console.log(item);
                                        var description = item.Name + ", " + "someStuff" + " (" + item.Code + ") ";
                                        return {
                                            label: description,
                                            value: description,
                                            code: item.Code
                                        }
                                    }))
                                });
```

but it looks like the only way to get it to work is to map either *CallingCode* or *CountryCode*, like this...

```
res($.map(data.CallingCode, function(item)
```

Then i have access to some info.

Is there a way i could map all the response to the item and then use it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this one is an issue for someone, the answer is pretty simple.
I was miss reading the response, it actually has one object with the info I need, the only thing to be aware of is the ExtensionData it has on it.

So i simply did this..

```
res($.map(data.CityList, function(item) {
   var description = item.Name + ", " + item.Country.Name + " (" + item.Country.Code + ") ";
```

The extension data used here is Country and you have to access to it normally.

Sometimes you overlook stuff that looks quite simple.

**Have a good day.**